# how to validate the exception thrown in ruby cucumber

Tags: ruby, methods, error-handling, null

How to handle null response in case if 500 response code
in ruby cucumber.

Below code snippet is to validate response code

```
expect (@response.code.to_s).to 
eq(response_code.to_s)
puts ( @response.code)
```

Comment: What do you mean "how to handle null response"? What do you want to happen? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a response with an empty body?

Rspec has built in http status matchers https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher

If you would like to check for a 500 status you can use this matcher:

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(500)
```